# Creating a Matrix constructor using initializer_list

Tags: c++

```
Matrix::Matrix(const i_list & list){

uint rows = list.size();
uint cols = list.begin()->size();
int cnt = 0;
mtrx = new double*[rows];

  for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
    mtrx[j] = new double[cols];
  }
  for(int k = 0; k < rows; k++){
    for(int l = 0; l < cols; l++){
      mtrx[k][l] = *(list.begin() + cnt);
      cnt++;
    }
  }

}
```

It keep giving me the error:

```
Matrix.cpp:30:15: error: cannot convert ‘const 
std::initializer_list<double>’ to ‘double’ in assignment
mtrx[k][l] = *(list.begin() + cnt);
           ^
```

Is there a way to convert that to a double? Casting doesn't work.

Comment: i_list is defined in my .h file typedef initializer_list<initializer_list<double>> i_list;

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet doesn't contain a definition of `i_list`, but it seems that it's an `std::initializer_list` of `initializer_list`s. Consequently,

```
*(list.begin() + cnt);
```

is an `initializer_list` object itself (an inner one), and not a `double`. That's the error message you're getting.

You might want to transform your double loop to something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

auto inner = std::begin(list);
for(int k = 0; k < rows; ++k, ++inner) 
    std::copy(std::begin(*inner), std::end(*inner), &mtrx[k][0]);
```

This iterates over the items of `list`; for each one, it replaces the inner loop by a call to [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, I infer that your `i_list` is a nested `initializer_list` like this:

```
std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>>
```

This means when you call `*(list.begin() + cnt)` (which is another way of writing `list.begin()[cnt]`) you don't get the `double` element but an inner list at position `cnt`.

To get the element, you have to first get the inner list at position `k`, then get the element at position `l` of that list:

```
mtrx[k][l] = list.begin()[k].begin()[l];
```

Comment: I tried that and it gave me this: Matrix.cpp:30:32: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const std::initializer_list<double>’ and ‘int’)
    mtrx[k][l] = list.begin()[k][l];

Comment: @CapnKirk Fixed.  Forgot `.begin()`